# Run .bat file via command propmt

Tags: server, wso2, command-prompt, findstr, wso2-esb

I am trying to start the `wso2server.bat` for the WSO2 Application Server. This is available inside `E:\wso2as-5.3.0\bin`. But I am currently encountering this error when running the file from the windows command prompt.

[image]

My Environment Variables are as follows.

- User Variable:

  - PATH: `F:\ESB\wso2as-5.3.0\bin`
- System Variable:

  - JAVA_HOME: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_144`
  - Path: `F:\ESB\wso2as-5.3.0\bin`

I've tried changing the Path Variables but I keep on getting this same error in starting the server.

Any suggestions in this regard will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you see findstr program in C:\WINDOWS\system32 directory?

Comment: That was what happened, I modified my User PATH variable to point to `C:\WINDOWS\system32`. Now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right Click My Compuer -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> System Variables -> Select Path variable -> append the below value.

Your user variable should look something like

```
F:\ESB\wso2as-5.3.0\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32
```

**Note**: I am assuming you installed your windows in C drive.

Comment: Thanks. Rather than adding a new path to my `PATH` I had edited it and hence `findstr` could not be accessed. Thanks again

Comment: @NayantaraJeyaraj, glad, your problem got solved. Would you please accept this as an answer? Sometimes it happens.